# Jquery getScript error in IE 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I am using jQuery 1.4.2 version and I have the following piece of code in my aspx page. It all works fine in all the browsers wxcept in IE 9

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.getScript("/MyScripts/ajaxpro/scripts.js")
         .done(function(script, textStatus) {

         })
         .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {

         });
});
```

I get the following error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'done': object is null or undefined
```

I am not able to figure this out. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why, but after modifying the code as below, every thing worked fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript("/MyScripts/ajaxpro/scripts.js");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This case work for me to solve the **SCRIPT5007** error:

I had this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;$("body").iealert({ <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;/* more code */<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;});<br>
});
```

And just added the $ symbol in the function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function( <i>**$**</i> ) { <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;$("body").iealert({ <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;/* more code */<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;});<br>
});<br>
```